# Selenium wont load link text - what am i missing

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to have Selenium click Accept on the cookie policy button before accessing the signup form. (I want to automate the waiting list functionality as it's always a race at this GYM) But I'm stuck at the first hurdle and have spent hours trying to decypher the error message. Can you please help?

Code

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://member.superfit.club/")

driver.find_element_by_link_text("Akzeptieren").click()
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Csongor\Dropbox\Coding\new test 6th oct 2020\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver.get("https://member.superfit.club/").find_element_by_link_text("Akzeptieren").click()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_link_text'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the button by the text value.

Try this code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://member.superfit.club/")

#driver.find_element_by_link_text("Akzeptieren").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Akzeptieren")]').click()
```

Comment: excellent, thank you! do you know of any cunning ways of running this script when a specific email comes in to my Gmail?

Comment: For gmail, you can try the Gmail API or connect using the IMAP module. Check these pages:API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python IMAP:  https://gist.github.com/robulouski/7441883

Answer (score 1):

The code you're showing doesn't reflect what's in your error stack trace. Apparently, you're calling `find_element_by_link_text` like this:

```py
driver.get("https://member.superfit.club/").find_element_by_link_text("Akzeptieren").click()
```

When you should do as you shown yourself:

```py
driver.get("https://member.superfit.club/")
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Akzeptieren").click()
```

Comment: excellent, thank you! do you know of any cunning ways of running this script when a specific email comes in to my Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't u just use `xpath` instead of `link text`?

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CookieModelButtom"]/div/div/div/div/button[1]').click()
```

This works perfectly fine. I recommend u to use `xpaths` or `CSS Selectors` instead of `Link Texts`.

Comment: excellent, thank you! do you know of any cunning ways of running this script when a specific email comes in to my Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

`find_element_by_link_text`() works for anchor element not button element .The element you are interacting it is button so you identify either ID,NAME,XPATH or CSS selector.

I would suggest you to use `WebDriverWait()` and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following css selector.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.btn.btn-success"))).click()
```

you need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```